# Is there a way to permanently modify the user string agent (Chromium browser)?

Tags: chromium

I like to use the most up to date version of Chromium, Google's open-source version of Chrome.  The problem I have about Chromium is that the userstring can always uniquely identify my system based on the version number (as not too many people keep up to date with the Chromium snapshots).

My question: is there a way to modify Chromium to always send out a DEFAULT user string agent (i.e. Chrome version 29 or Firefox 24, not Chrome 32)? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a command line option for that, e.g.

```
chromium-browser --user-agent="Chrome version 29"
```

For more details see this page: [Chromium tips and tweaks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chromium_Tips_and_Tweaks#User_Agent).

(Note: I'm not sure if it will work in future versions)